# Pass jQuery score variable to Facebook Share Code

Tags: jquery, share

I have a jquery quiz that returns a value out of 10.

What I want to do have is "share to facebook" and "tweet your score" buttons after the user takes the quiz.

This is the code im using for the links:

```
<a class="facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=<?=urlencode("https://www.facebook.com/=app_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");?>&display=page&link=<?=urlencode("https://www.facebook.com/=app_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");?>&picture=<?=urlencode("");?>&caption=&description=<?=urlencode("I just took the Quiz and scored xx/10. Want to take the quiz? Click here.");?>&name=<?=urlencode("");?>" title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank">Share on Facebook</a>

  <a href="http://twitter.com?status=<?=urlencode("I just took the Quiz and scored xx/10. Want to take the quiz? Click here.");?>" title="Tweet" target="_blank" class="twitter">Share on Twitter</a>
```

So I'd like the xx/10 in the description to show the users score, which is stored in a jQuery variable.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, a jQuery variable is just a Javascript variable. And since it looks like PHP is outputting that text, that means you have to pass the value of the Javascript variable to your PHP script when the score is submitted.

You'll either have to catch the form submit with Javascript, or submit the form with Javascript.

Alternatively, you can just create a session based quiz, and calculate the results in PHP.